# How to create dynamic HTML files and send it to the email using javascript

Tags: javascript

i am creating a web app. In this app its required to create dynamic webpage and send it via email. I am able to create HTML file but don't know how to automatically send this to email. my code for creating html file is given below.

```
function download(filename, text) {
var element = document.createElement('a');
element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
element.setAttribute('download', filename);
element.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(element);
element.click();
document.body.removeChild(element);
};
```

It stores HTML file localy but i need to send this file when its creating. I try something like this.

```
let t=download(filename+".html",cont).getAttribute("href");
let sp=decodeURIComponent(t).toString().replace("data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,","");
sendMail(sp,mail,stdmail);
function sendMail(sp,mail,stdmail) {
var link = "mailto:"+mail
    + "?cc=example@gmail.com"
    + "&subject=" + escape("This is my subject")
    + "&body=" + sp
    ;
window.location.href = link;
}
```

This approach just show "ObjectHTMLElement" in email message body. One important note i need to create this with javascript not php.

Comment: You receive `ObjectHTMLElement` because of bad toString() conversation somewhere in your code

Comment: so what is your suggestion?

Comment: Also, your download function only downloads HTML file to your computer and don't return anything

Comment: My suggestion is that you don't need to use download at all and you need to provide your email content via body param. Why don't you just escape your `cont` variable?

Comment: so what am i suppose to do please give some correction.

Comment: You need to find a way to pass your `cont` variable content via `body` get param in your URL

Comment: If any one know how to solve please help me to solve i have been stucked here for three days.

Comment: If you mean you want the HTML to render in the email itself, this tutorial explains how to do that from a Node.js server. https://stackabuse.com/how-to-send-emails-with-node-js/ If you're trying do it from the client side, I'm not sure how that would work but maybe this library could be of use? https://pepipost.com/tutorials/how-to-send-emails-with-javascript/